# Unexpected key 'FilterPolicy' found in params

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html lists that you can add a FilterPolicy in the attributes, but when I do so I get:

```
index.js:1 UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key &#39;FilterPolicy&#39; found in params
at ParamValidator.fail (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:238942:37)
at ParamValidator.validateStructure (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:238969:14)
at ParamValidator.validateMember (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:238978:21)
at ParamValidator.validate (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:238926:10)
at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:237086:42)
at Request.callListeners (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:242603:20)
at callNextListener (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:242590:12)
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:237039:9
at finish (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:232861:7)
at getStaticCredentials (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:232890:7)
```

```
  static async AddAlert(devEui, protocol, endpoint)
  {
    var params = {
      Protocol: protocol, /* required */
      TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789:Alert', /* required */
      FilterPolicy: {
        "dev_eui": [
          devEui
        ]
      },
      Endpoint: endpoint,
      ReturnSubscriptionArn: true 
    };

    var promise = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2010-03-31'})
    .subscribe(params).promise()
    .catch(
      function(err) {
        console.error(err, err.stack);
        throw err;
      })
    return promise;
  }
```

Comment: You didn't indicate which SDK call you're making or provide any code.

Comment: Added what you asked for @jarmod

Comment: FilterPolicy should be under Attributes.

Comment: @jarmod Wow I read that wrong. Thanks that's right! I also had to make the JSON a string for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put the Filter Policy under Attributes per Jarmon comment

```
static async AddAlert(devEui, protocol, endpoint)
  {
    var params = {
      Protocol: protocol, /* required */
      TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789:Alert', /* required */
      Attributes: FilterPolicy: JSON.stringify({
        "dev_eui": [
          devEui
        ]
      }),
      Endpoint: endpoint,
      ReturnSubscriptionArn: true 
    };

    var promise = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2010-03-31'})
    .subscribe(params).promise()
    .catch(
      function(err) {
        console.error(err, err.stack);
        throw err;
      })
    return promise;
  }
```